# wordpress site is not displaying properly in IE

Tags: css, html, wordpress, internet-explorer

My HTML5 Wordpress `<a href="#">site</a>` is not showing properly in IE, but it works well in Chrome and Firefox. What is the reason for this and how can I resolve it?

Comment: It can be alarming to see your great website in IE for the first time. But don't worry, it's normally not that hard to fix. However, for us to be able to help you, please tell us what is not displaying correctly, and post the relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: it displaying things not in correct order and not in correct places. there is ie.css file but i dont know whether it uses or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using html 5 elements try to add that in css like

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
```

it ll work fine.
or simply try to add this code to html

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: i added it but still no change... i added the same u mentioned in my sytle.css but it looks same as before.

Comment: see this url http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/

Comment: thanks radha.. now its fine

Comment: hai radha.. what is that link in script used for? i'm a fresher that's why i'm asking..

Answer (score 0):

Check that have you add html 5 doctype in header or not. 
 or used it.